# how to convert 1.1760481E7 to 11760481 in java

Tags: java

Is there any function to convert `1.1760481E7` `double` value to `String` value. I tried `Double.toString(value)`. I am getting above format. But I need `11760481` in this format.

Comment: `NumberFormat` is the class you are looking for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `BigDecimal` to get `String` value.

```
double val = 1.1760481E7;
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(val);// form to BigDecimal
String str=bigDecimal.toString();// get the String value
System.out.println(str);
```

Out put:

```
11760481
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `String.format()`. See below example

```
Double d = 1.1760481E7;

System.out.println(String.format("%.0f", d));
```

Output

```
11760481
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [java.text.DecimalFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) which has all sorts of [formatting possibilities](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html) and is particularly suited to displaying human readable values on user interfaces, e.g. comma separators and other locale support. It works well for single values, if you want to combine it in a larger string, I'd use String.format() mentioned in the other answer.

"#" converts the value without comma separators

```
double val = 1.1760481E7;
DecimalFormat format = new DecimalFormat("#");
String str = format.format(val);
System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

use  **`String.format("%.0f", 1.1760481E7)`**